# Audio class in javascript returning undefined for duration

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a simple music player using HTML, CSS and javascript. I want to access the inner children of the span given below:

```
<div class="songItem">
   <img alt="1">
   <span class="songName">Let Me Love You</span>
   <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timestamp">05:34 <i id="3" class="far songItemPlay fa-play-circle"></i></span></span>
</div>
```

I have 10 songs, so the above code is repeated 10 times.

I also have an array which holds the song information in the form of objects:

```
var songs = [
    {songName: "Warriyo - Mortals [NCS Release]", filePath: "songs/1.mp3", coverPath: "covers/1.jpg"},
    {songName: "Cielo - Huma-Huma", filePath: "songs/2.mp3", coverPath: "covers/2.jpg"},
    {songName: "DEAF KEV - Invincible [NCS Release]-320k", filePath: "songs/3.mp3", coverPath: "covers/3.jpg"},
    {songName: "Different Heaven & EH!DE - My Heart [NCS Release]", filePath: "songs/4.mp3", coverPath: "covers/4.jpg"},
    {songName: "Janji-Heroes-Tonight-feat-Johnning-NCS-Release", filePath: "songs/5.mp3", coverPath: "covers/5.jpg"},
    {songName: "Rabba - Salam-e-Ishq", filePath: "songs/2.mp3", coverPath: "covers/6.jpg"},
    {songName: "Sakhiyaan - Salam-e-Ishq", filePath: "songs/2.mp3", coverPath: "covers/7.jpg"},
    {songName: "Bhula Dena - Salam-e-Ishq", filePath: "songs/2.mp3", coverPath: "covers/8.jpg"},
    {songName: "Tumhari Kasam - Salam-e-Ishq", filePath: "songs/2.mp3", coverPath: "covers/9.jpg"},
    {songName: "Na Jaana - Salam-e-Ishq", filePath: "songs/4.mp3", coverPath: "covers/10.jpg"},
]
```

I am using the `Audio()` class of javascript like this:

`var audioElement = new Audio("songs/1.mp3")`

I am applying a for-each loop on the `songItems` array to fill the song UI. However when I try to access the text present in `timestamp` of the and set it to the duration of the song, I am getting `undefined`.

```
songItems.forEach((element, i) => {
    element.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = songs[i].coverPath
    element.getElementsByClassName("songName")[0].innerText = songs[i].songName
    element.getElementsByClassName("songlistplay")[0].getElementsByClassName("timestamp")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = audioElement.duration.toString();
})
```

Output:

[image: error]

Why am I getting `undefined` for the duration?

Kindly comment if more information is needed.

**Edit:**

I added the following code but it still isn't working:

```
audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    console.log(audioElement.duration.toString())
})
```

Comment: Because loading the audio data is async, you must wait for the `audio.onloadedmetadata` event

Comment: It's not working for me. I added the same code as the given answer

Comment: You mean `NaN` is being logged in the console or you literally have that `console.log(audioElement.duration.toString())` call in your updated code and still see the `NaN` value in your player? If the latter, you need to change `console.log()` with your utterly long `element.getElementsByClassName(`...`.nodeValue = audioElement.duration.toString();`

Comment: `NaN` is logged in console(first one). `Audio` object is not getting initialized with the song.

Comment: So the loadedmetadata event doesn't fire? Your path may not point to a valid audio file. What does the "network" tab of your dev-tools say?

Comment: I am pointing to the correct song location. I am not using any internet in the website, I have the songs locally

Comment: You could still face network issues, moreover from the `file://` protocol where a lot of restrictions are in place and where the OS may not return the correct headers expected by the browser. So, please, look at that Network panel of your dev-tools and tell us what you see there, and please confirm clearly if the event fires or not. If it doesn't fire it means that the URL doesn't point to a media file the browser is able to read. You could in that case even check for the `audioElement.error` property it may contain more info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243809/discussion-between-aditya-dixit-and-kaiido).